# Java to C++ conversion of UI + logic + DB quering

Tags: java, c++, data-access-layer

I need some help in pointing me, how to **convert*** this code below to C++

```
<html><body>
<table>
<%
while( rs.next() ){
%><tr>
<td><%=rs.getString("id") %></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("date") %></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("email") %></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
<%}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{
if(con!=null) con.close();
}
%>
</body></html>
```

convert* means write something similar - with mixed and messed up layers (this is actually all-in-1 layer)

But, to be honest, I want you to suggest me some readings about data-access-layer and web interfaces in C++, because I have never done such things in C++, just some simple procedural / OOP

big thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps as an introduction to interpreting web scripting languages. JSP (and ASP and PHP) are actually "Inside-Out Code"[1]. They look like code embedded in text, but that is just an ***illusion***......

- `<%=EXPRESSION%>` becomes `<%Response.Write(EXPRESSION)%>`
- `<% STATEMENTS %>` becomes `"); STATEMENTS; Response.Write(@"`
- Prepend `Response.Write(@"` and Append `");`

... And you have pretty much got your program.

So yours becomes:

```
Response.Write(@"
<html><body>
<table>
");try{
while( rs.next() ){
Response.Write(@"<tr>
<td>"); Response.Write(rs.getString("id")); Response.Write(@"</td>
<td>"); Response.Write(rs.getString("date")); Response.Write(@"</td>
<td>"); Response.Write(rs.getString("date")); Response.Write(@"</td>
</tr>
");}Response.Write(@"
");}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{
if(con!=null) con.close();
}
Response.Write(@"
</body></html>");
```

Put like that, and with a littel bit of reformatting, you can see that it is actually a very simple program, and conversion should be equally simple.

The difficult bit will be converting things like the database access library.

[1] OK it is a little bit more complicated than that, but that's basically it. The JSP/PHP/ASP file goes through a preprocessor which converts all the directives to Java/VBScript/C#/Whatever, which will look much like what I show above. The result is recognisable as a bog-standard computer program which is then compiled/interpreted and run.

Comment: @dantuch, no, sorry I don't think such a thing exists. The point of my answer was to allow you to see the similarity between JSP and regular programming languages. To write a web application in C++ you need the CGI, NSAPI and ISAPI documentation, and a ***really, really good reason***. :-) JSP/ASP/PHP are used because they are good at web applications.

Comment: There are still companies that code using C++ (so I'm sure they do web application too), willing to teach thier developers to use design-pattens and show some anti-pattern is my reason :) ... so any help is needed, because i know NONE about wep application with C++ ;) and it that wont change I'll be forced to use desktop samples

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with C++ web applications, other than to say "don't do it", and then point you towards the documentation for CGI, NSAPI and ISAPI. CGI is the easiest of the three. Cheers, Ben